# Show find/search results starting from the first result visible on my page view

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge, safari

On Safari or Edge, when I do command-F to search for a keyword like "apple", it goes straight to the top of the page for the first time "apple" is mentioned. This can be very disorienting as I don't know where in the page I was. Can it start from the first "apple" at the current visible page view? This is a feature that I take for granted on VS Code.